# Disable scroll background on showing customize popup

Tags: javascript, css, cordova

I'm using Cordova to build Android/IOS app with Javascript

Versions:

```
cordova-android: 6.2.3
cordova-ios: 4.4.0
```

Before continue actions, user must be re-ask to confirm. A comfirmation popup will be displayed.

Problem is user can scroll background screen when popup shown in their own device. In development environment (browser), its working perfectly by setting popup wrapper full size of screen. I need disable scrolling in device for this case.

What are the best and simplest ways to fixed it? 
Sorry for my bad English!

Comment: How about showing the code relevant to the issue?

Answer (score 0):

```
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
```

put above line in your config.xml.

Answer (score 0):

JS solution could be putting :

```
document.querySelector('body').classList.add('noscroll');
```

just before the confirmation popup.
And remove it after:

```
document.querySelector('body').classList.remove('noscroll');
```

where `noscroll` is a class defined in (for example) in styles.css:

```
.noscroll {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```